# Why UIWebView anchor's target is ignored?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I have a `UIWebView` embedded within an iPhone app I am developing.
I am trying to make the links open in Safari by using target="_blank" on anchors.

I see that the target property is ignored by the `UIWebView`, links do not open in a new Safari instance. Why is that?

I know that in order to make this work I have to use `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `openURL` to make Safari open a web page from your app:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."]];
```

If you want to "intercept" the tap on a given link and open Safari with that URL, you can use, as you say, `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`. I would suggest to use a custom scheme for the protocol of your URL, so you can differentiate links that should open in Safari from links that can be open in your `UIWebView`:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:@"safari"])
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"safari://" withString:@"http://"]];

 }
```

In this case, you would specify your urls in the HTML page as "safari://..."

Otherwise, simply call `openURL` passing the full URL to it.

Comment: it does not answer my question. i wanted to know why _blank doesn't work. i already said I know the workaround is shouldStartLoadWithRequest

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try something like:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```